# Event Sourcing and synchronous reads. Is it possible?

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, event-sourcing, eventual-consistency

Just can't find any definitive answer online. I'd like to employ ES for my project, but what bugs me is it's asynchronous nature.
Consider a collaborative blog site (I'm making stuff up for the sake of simplicity as my domain is far more complex).
Users can create blog posts and edit them. That's it, nothing more.
So, I've just created a blog entry with

```
createBlogEntryCommand = new CreateBlogEntryCommand(body, tags)
createBlogEntryCommand.execute()
```

With ES I'd store `BlogEntryCreatedEvent` in the ES store, something like

```
eventStore.append({
    "id": "1d11071c-33c6-4621-bb86-cafcc3ca23a6",
    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....",
    "tags": ["awesome-reading", "awesome-writing"],
})
```

Now, I have no idea when a consumer will pick this event up and process. Of course, I can have a heuristic metric and guarantee to some degree this event will be processed in X ms, but what if the consumer is down for maintenance, for instance? How do I make the blog entry available for the author straight away?

Sure enough, I can poll the database for blog id of `1d11071c-33c6-4621-bb86-cafcc3ca23a6` (since it's pre-generated, so issuing ids is not a DB concern) and once consumer has picked the event and created materialised view in the database, make it available for the user, but ***is it the only way***?

> P.S. I watched a lot of videos online on the subject, I have read a ton of blogs too, but any source seems to be circumventing this caveat of ES not explaining any approaches. Most often then not, the answer I've heard "this can be resolved on UI/UX level". So if there are good books / articles / videos that are discussing how to overcome ES pitfalls in details, please share in the comments.

**UPDATE**

Reading history for synchronisation straight away... I actually thought about this, but refused this idea really quickly.
Considering a simple todo app where a user can sign up and create todo list, I envision having something like

> UserRegistered
>
> TodoCreated
>
> TodoUpdated
>
> TodoCompleted
>
> TodoDeleted
>
> TodoUnDeleted

When reading events from the events store, I'm not interested in other user's todo items, but I'm only interested in current user's todo items. Which means having a store of events like so:

> **UserRegistered** {name: Bob, id: 1}
>
> UserRegistered {name: Alice, id: 2}
>
> **TodoCreated** {id: 123, todo: Buy milk, user: 1}
>
> **TodoUpdated** {id: 123, todo: Buy skim milk, user: 1}
>
> **TodoCompleted** {id: 123}
>
> TodoCreated {id: 456, todo: Pay the dues, user: 2}
>
> TodoCompleted {id: 456}
>
> **TodoDeleted** {id: 123}
>
> **TodoUnDeleted** {id: 123}
>
> **TodoUpdated** {id: 123, todo: Buy full cream milk!, user: 1}

If I'd be required to get the latest state of Bob's todo id 123 (buy milk), I'd need to read ALL the events despite though they might be nothing to do with Bob's list of items. So I'd be traversing through heaps of events of todos created by other users apart from Bob to only filter and apply Bob's ones.

Does it mean I will be required to have a special "channel" in my events store to only contain Bob's actions upon todo items.
In addition, what if somebody else is able to manage Bob's todo list items? What if Alice has an access to modify Bob's todos? Won't it greatly increase events storage schema?

Comment: Bounty will be awarded to the current accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it the only way?

No.

There is *nothing* wrong with reading a history of events out of the event store, and then using those events to compute your view on demand.

```
View v = View.from(events);
```

> Does it mean I will be required to have a special "channel" in my events store to only contain Bob's actions upon todo items. In addition, what if somebody else is able to manage Bob's todo list items? What if Alice has an access to modify Bob's todos? Won't it greatly increase events storage schema?

The usual answer is that events that belong together will share a correlation id, and the message store allows you to specify which key to use.

For example, if you were using an RDBMS as your store, you might have a single blob column for all of your event data, and then a number of additional columns to store bits of meta data that are useful for retrieval.

Access rules (who can make changes) are a separate concern from the context of the events themselves (who are the events about).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have updated my question as this way of synchronisation I have refused a while ago and didn't event mention (I didn't even try to implement it, really), because I cant really make it work.

Comment: Thank you for the update, it makes a lot of sense to use the correlation id for the events that are bound together.

Comment: BTW, what would be your go-to solution for events store? I'm using `kafka` ATM

Comment: Postgres.  Until you know which hard problems you need to solve: keep it simple.